# Lebesgue measure: $\lim_{t\to 0} m((B+t)\cap B)=m(B) $?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Here is a question. If $B$ is a set in $\mathbb{R}$ of finite measure, do we have that:

$$\lim_{t\to 0} m(B_t∩B)=m(B),$$

here $B_t$ denotes the t-translated set: $B_t= B+t$ and $t$ is a real number.

I tried to use the dominated convergence theorem on $X_{B_t\cap B}<X_B$, but then we don't have the point-wise convergence. So I guess we must go back to the basic theory of measurable sets to solve it ?

Comment: @IsmailAbouamal Do you know that the convolution of bounded functions is continuous?

Comment: @IsmailAbouamal I think it would be best if you edited your answer including your comment on what you tried

Comment: @clark If this is true, then the problem is solved! Yes of course it's a good idea, I'll edit it then.

Comment: @clark any reference where I can see that: the convolution of bounded functions is continuous. I know that this is true somewhere for Fourier transforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the right idea to use the Lebesgue convergence theorem. I was not able to show the point-wise converge because of the sets were originally arbitrary. However, by assuming first that $B$ is open, we can show that indeed we have the point-wise convergence, hence the result is true for open intervals. Once we have that, we use the original definition of Lebesgue measure to find open intervals that approximate our general measurable set $B$ and then prove the result in general.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a finite union of open intervals $I = I_1 \cup I_2 \cup \ldots \cup I_n$ such that $\mu( B \mathbin{\Delta} I ) \leqslant \varepsilon$. So first show that the claim holds for intervals, then for finite unions of intervals, then use the above approximation.